# Sony Vaio VPCEH18FG backlight problem

Tags: 12.04, brightness, vaio, sony

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Sony Vaio VPCEH18FG but the screen brightness does not change with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5/F6</kbd> keys and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file is also not found.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

LCD Brightness Control

Once you have installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers as suggested above, you may notice that your brightness control keys do not work properly. This is fixable by editing one's xorg.conf file. Open a terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Append a line so it appears like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You will need to restart your graphical server (or reboot) for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Xorg -configure**

You can create a basic xorg.conf using the X executable itself. As root run:

```
  Xorg :1 -configure
```

This will create the file /root/xorg.conf.new, which you can then copy to */etc/X11/xorg.conf*:

```
  cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and edit it according to:

```
  Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
  EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

**TO CREATE ''xorg.conf''**  in /etc/X11/

in terminal

```
# nvidia-xconfig
```

this creates /etc/X11/xorg.conf . edit it.